# High daily mileage preparation

Tags: maintenance, mileage, preventive-maintenance

I know a couple of people who started driving for Lyft and Uber.  One of those people plan on doing it full time.  I know they haven't even thought of what driving hundreds of miles a day might do to their car.  I'm not a "car guy," but I know enough to ask.  What kind of preparations and preventative maintenance should someone do to their car if they plan on putting hundreds of miles a day on their car?  What about ongoing maintenance?

Comment: I would start by see what the owners manuals suggests for "severe" or "heavy duty" service intervals

Comment: Don't forget there are  *benefits* from this type of usage - for example, you will hardly ever be driving with a cold engine, with cold lubricants (more viscous) and richer fuel-air mixtures with the excess fuel getting into the oil, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintenance for these types of situations aren't going to be any different than doing it any other time ... other than it will need to be done more often. More miles = More maintenance more often.

There are some things which can be done to mitigate this effect, such as:

- Use an oil which will last longer. Amsoil (12k miles or 12 months, whichever comes first) or Mobil1 Annual Protection (20k miles or 12 months, whichever comes first) will prolong the life of the oil. This will take your car down the road further with fewer oil changes. Use the corresponding filter to help with that longevity.
- When replacement of wear parts is needed, use quality, heavy duty parts. For instance, on most vehicles you can find brake parts which are considered heavy duty. I found rotors which were made for vehicles which cops use for my truck. I assume these should last a little longer than Chinesium rotors.

**NOTE:** When talking about "heavy duty", do not confuse this with "performance" parts when it comes to brakes. Performance brakes will stop better, but that's because they are made of more aggressive materials, which means they wear faster. Both will get you stopped, but the performance ones will not last near as long.

- Purchase tires which are long lasting ones. Getting a tire which is good for 70k miles is a lot better idea than purchasing tires which are only good to 40k. Just the replacement savings alone makes it worth it (the cost of getting the tires mounted/balanced/core throw away charge/etc/etc/etc ... it all adds up).
- Speaking of tires, when you put new ones on, ensure you purchase an alignment plan. Many shops offer 1, 2, or 3 year plans. You can get the vehicle aligned as much as you'd like during that period. Running around a lot, with stopping/going, curbs, etc, will most likely cause your alignment to go out of sorts sooner. Get a plan which will cover these events. While it costs a bit more up front, it will pay for itself soon enough. A good alignment will save wear/tear on your tires, a better ride, and better fuel economy.
- Ensure the car is properly tuned, with all regular maintenance kept up to date. Each fluid in the car has an expiration date/distance involved with it. Follow your owner's manual for "severe duty" and you'll be golden. Doing the proper maintenance when it's needed means your car will be less likely to leave you and/or your passengers stranded.

I'm sure there are other things which could be added, but hopefully this gives you an idea of what you need to be doing.

If you're doing Uber or Lyft, remember, your car is your lifeblood. Treat it as a business. Since your car is your business, it only makes sense to take care of it fully.

Comment: Should there be a lot of short term trips:

Install an AGM battery, as those are suited for start-stop use. Perhaps change it preventively every few years. Be prepared for an early starter replacement

Comment: @Myself - Good points!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check all fluids and tyre pressure and profile. Make this your daily routine.
2. If it was used only for sporadic short term trips, it may be wise to change the oil. A lot of cold-starts can dilute the oil and a sudden long trip can than increase wear.
3. When your tyre has worn out, look closely which one to get. There are some that last longer than others, and some that may reduce fuel consumption a little.